# jquery UI widgets without the CSS bloat

Tags: jquery-ui

A question about jquery UI widgets. Is there a way to get them without all the bloat of CSS that they carry and render out ? I'm having a complete mess with tabs rendering all those jquery-ui-widget, jquery-ui-panel etc. etc. classes.

This guy here does it somehow
http://www.davereederdesign.com/post/2010/04/23/Tabs-with-Memory.aspx

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He doesn't use the JQuery Tab widget.

Comment: Yeah I see but still is there a way to separate jquery widgets from their CSS?

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs that could prevent all the css classes from being applied so I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know this as an old post, but I'm having a similar problem applying UI widgets to an already very heavy website.  If you inspected the widget in Firebug you might be able to only grab the rules that the widget uses and create a custom CSS file to apply to it.  I'm going to try this when I'm back at work tomorrow and I'll report back on my progress.